# Is there a better way to implement this MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

`Y = zeros(5000,10);`
`y` is a 5000 x 1 predefined vector consisting of numbers from 1 to 10;

```
for i= 1:size(Y,1)
    Y(i,y(i)) = 1;
end
```

Is there a better and simpler way to implement this since the rest of my code is vectorized and does not contain any for loop

Comment: This code is probably quite fast as it is, because you are doing really little things inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use bsxfun:

```
bsxfun(@eq,y,[1:10])
```

Instead of your code, you can create each row using `y(i)==[1:10]` which is finally wrapped in bsxfun to vectorize.

Another idea would be index calculation:

```
Y((y-1).*5000+(1:5000).')=1;
```

Comment: Nice catch @Daniel. However the returned matrix appears to be logical, even if you preallocate it with `zeros()`. A `double()` conversion might be required.

Comment: And on my system this is way slower than the `for` loop ... (with conversion)

Comment: to me, the `bsxfun()`, including the `double()` conversion, takes half the time with respect to the `for` loop (0.002190s vs 0.005001s)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sub2ind`:

```
Y(sub2ind(size(Y), 1:size(Y, 1), y')) = 1;
```

However, this might actually be slightly slower:

```
Y = zeros(5000,10);
y = randi(10, 5000, 1);

tic
for jj = 1:1000
    for i = 1:size(Y,1)
        Y(i,y(i)) = 1;
    end
end
toc
% Elapsed time is 0.126774 seconds.

tic
for jj = 1:1000
    Y(sub2ind(size(Y), 1:size(Y, 1), y')) = 1;
end
toc
% Elapsed time is 0.139531 seconds.

% @Daniel's solution
tic
for jj = 1:1000
    Y = double(bsxfun(@eq, y, 1:10));
end
toc
%Elapsed time is 0.187331 seconds.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach: create a [`sparse`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix using `y` as column indices, and then convert to [`full`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html) if needed:

```
Y = full(sparse(1:numel(y), y, 1, numel(y), 10));
```